# Ktor server, a correct way to receive messages from websocket

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm new in Ktor-server and don't fully understand how web sockets receive messages. I found several solutions in different sources. (`try\catch` and `webscoket` blocks are omitted)

1. `while(true)` way

```
        while(true){
            val incoming = receiveDeserialized<IncomingDto>()
            MessageService.newMessage(incoming)   
        }
```

2. `consumeEach` way

```
        incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
               // process frame
        }
```

3. `flow` way

```
        incoming.receiveAsFlow().filterIsInstance<Frame.Text>()
                .collect{
               // process frame
         }
```

4. `for` way

```
        for (frame in incoming){
            frame as? Frame.Text ?: continue
            // process frame
        }
```

Which way is correct? Or do they do the same thing?

---

Second question. Should I need to use `async{}` inside the receive block so as not to block the receive channel. For example

```
 while(true){
     val incoming = receiveDeserialized<IncomingDto>()
     async{
         println("starting heavy task")
// heavy task
         delay(500)
         println("task complete")
     }
 
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These are different methods of working with [ReceiveChannel](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/) so use one that better suits your needs. The difference between `consumeEach` and `for` loop is described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/consume-each.html). In the `while(true)` example you receive and deserialize (using an installed content converter) a frame. In the `flow` example [receiveAsFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/receive-as-flow.html?query=fun%20%3CT%3E%20ReceiveChannel%3CT%3E.receiveAsFlow():%20Flow%3CT%3E) is used
   to represent the given receive channel as a hot flow.
2. Yes. You can use `async` or `launch` to not block receiving other frames.

Comment: How to use `receiveDeserialized`?

Comment: https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-serialization.html